# category->categories view in admin causes error: Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException): Requested store is not found

Tags: admin, magento2.2

Imported data from version 1.9.3.  Set the stores to single store mode.  Developer mode enabled.  Cache cleared, indexes rebuilt.  I tried turning single store mode off and adding a new store so that there is a storeid 2.  But then it creates the same error for storeid 3.  And if I add another store, or mess with the storeid values in the database, the error will go to storeid 3, and 4, etc.

I have literally no idea what could be happening.

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException): Requested store is not found

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException): Requested store is not found
 #0 /html/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreManager.php(167): Magento\Store\Model\StoreRepository->getById('2')
 #1 /html/vendor/magento/module-cms/Model/ResourceModel/AbstractCollection.php(85): Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager->getStore('2')
 #2 /html/vendor/magento/module-cms/Model/ResourceModel/Block/Collection.php(30): Magento\Cms\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractCollection->performAfterLoad('cms_block_store', 'block_id')
 #3 /html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection/AbstractDb.php(588): Magento\Cms\Model\ResourceModel\Block\Collection->_afterLoad()
 #4 /html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection/AbstractDb.php(559): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->loadWithFilter(false, false)
 #5 /html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Category/Attribute/Source/Page.php(40): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->load()
 #6 /html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Category/DataProvider.php(338): Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Attribute\Source\Page->getAllOptions()
 #7 /html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\DataProvider->getAttributesMeta(Object(Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Type))
 #8 /html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\DataProvider\Interceptor->___callParent('getAttributesMe...', Array)
 #9 /html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\DataProvider\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Type))
 #10 /html/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Category/DataProvider/Interceptor.php(65): Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\DataProvider\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getAttributesMe...', Array, Array)
 #11 /html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Category/DataProvider.php(262): Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\DataProvider\Interceptor->getAttributesMeta(Object(Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Type))
 #12 /html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\DataProvider->prepareMeta(Array)
 #13 /html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\DataProvider\Interceptor->___callParent('prepareMeta', Array)
 #14 /html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\DataProvider\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Array)
 #15 /html/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Category/DataProvider/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\DataProvider\Interceptor->___callPlugins('prepareMeta', Array, Array)
 #16 /html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Category/DataProvider.php(198): Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\DataProvider\Interceptor->prepareMeta(Array)
 #17 /html/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Category/DataProvider/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\DataProvider->getMeta()
 #18 /html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php(302): Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\DataProvider\Interceptor->getMeta()
 #19 /html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php(208): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->mergeMetadata('category_form', Array, true)
 #20 /html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(135): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->create('category_form', NULL, Array)
 #21 /html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(97): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->generateComponent(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Data\Structure), 'category_form', Array, Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor))
 #22 /html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/GeneratorPool.php(80): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context))
 #23 /html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(344): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context))
 #24 /html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(89): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->generateElements()
 #25 /html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(129): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->generateElements()
 #26 /html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Builder.php(55): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
 #27 /html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(65): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
 #28 /html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(254): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build()
 #29 /html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(875): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->build()
 #30 /html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(414): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getBlock('menu')
 #31 /html/vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/View/Result/Page.php(26): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getBlock('menu')
 #32 /html/generated/code/Magento/Backend/Model/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page->setActiveMenu('Magento_Catalog...')
 #33 /html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Category/Edit.php(103): Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->setActiveMenu('Magento_Catalog...')
 #34 /html/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Category/Edit/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Edit->execute()
 #35 /html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(107): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Edit\Interceptor->execute()
 #36 /html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(229): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
 #37 /html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
 #38 /html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Edit\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
 #39 /html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(143): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Edit\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
 #40 /html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Edit\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
 #41 /html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Edit\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
 #42 /html/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Category/Edit/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Edit\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, NULL)
 #43 /html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Edit\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
 #44 /html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
 #45 /html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
 #46 /html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
 #47 /html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
 #48 /html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
 #49 /html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
 #50 /html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
 #51 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

To Solve this error ,you have to modify StoreManager.php

> (/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreManager.php)

If **$storeId** is not defined: It retrive data from COOKIE first, otherwise return the default store code.
At line 154 replace with the below patch:

```
if (!isset($storeId) || '' === $storeId || $storeId === true) {
            if (null === $this->currentStoreId) {
                \Magento\Framework\Profiler::start('store.resolve');
                $this->currentStoreId = $this->storeResolver->getCurrentStoreId();
                \Magento\Framework\Profiler::stop('store.resolve');
            }
            $storeId = $this->currentStoreId;
        }
```

**TO**

```
 if(!$storeId){
            if(isset($_COOKIE['store']) && $_COOKIE['store'] !== ''){
                $storeId = $_COOKIE['store'];
            } else {
                $storeId = $this->getDefaultStoreView()->getCode();
            }           
        }
```

Comment: Not working.. :(